# where should I put the action for a button inside a UITableViewDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewDelegate, as the following

```
class CusinePreferencesTableView: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentefiers.oneCusinePreferencesCell.rawValue, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OneCusinePreferencesTableViewCell
//do bla bla bla with the cell
        cell.leftButton.addTarget(self, action: "cusineClicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
        cell.rightButton.addTarget(self, action: "cusineClicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
        cell.setNeedsDisplay()
        return cell
    }
```

my cell has two buttons, and as you see, I'm setting actions for them.

I'm getting exception states that `unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa660ecbfa0`

I tried to put the

```
func buttonClicked(sender: PreferenceButton){
        // do bla bla bla
    }
```

in both the `CusinePreferencesTableView` and inside the UIViewController that has an outlet for the UITableView, and which is using CusinePreferencesTableView as its delegate, but I kept with that exception having it

Help please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `CusinePreferencesTableView` add the button's action

```
func cusineClicked(sender: PreferenceButton){
        print("action triggered")
    }
```

The action name that was set when target was added to the button is different from action (different names) you have actually implemented in the class.

Comment: your button action has 'cusineClicked:'  name, but you implement it with 'buttonClicked' name, the system won't find it and it will crash